# How to extract Base64 (not base64 encoding) value from SHA-256 hash in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a test string "abc" on which I will be using SHA-256 Jmeter function (i.e. ${__digest(SHA-256,abc,,,)}) but this will only return the HEX value (i.e. "ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad"). I need the base64 value (i.e. "ungWv48Bz+pBQUDeXa4iI7ADYaOWF3qctBD/YfIAFa0=") [which is different from the base64 encoded value]. Is there any way to convert a hex value to only base64 and not base64 encoded value ?

For references see this site : https://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator

And here are the results :

- hex: ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad
- base64: **ungWv48Bz+pBQUDeXa4iI7ADYaOWF3qctBD/YfIAFa0=** (I need this value)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mohit, I guess you need to change the question. It should be from `hex` to `base64`. Please check the follow script.

Please add this in a `BeanShell PreProcessor`

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

String creds = "${__digest(SHA-256,abc,,,)}";

byte[] decodedHexNEW = Hex.decodeHex(creds.toCharArray());
String result = Base64.encodeBase64String(decodedHexNEW);

log.info("HEX TO BASE 64----------------->"+result);

//vars.put("convertedString",new String(result));
```

This will convert what you are expecting,

[image]

[image]

ungWv48Bz+pBQUDeXa4iI7ADYaOWF3qctBD/YfIAFa0= `[Expected String]`
ungWv48Bz+pBQUDeXa4iI7ADYaOWF3qctBD/YfIAFa0= `[Result String]`

For more reference, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: Thanks @Jyoti thihs piece of code also worked like a charm.
I am not familiar with much coding, so please excuse my silly question here :
- How to use the variable "result" in other requests I tried using it with syntax "${result}" but was not able to use it. If you could help me out in this too ?

Comment: Please enable the last line `vars.put("convertedString",new String(result));` and after that you can use it either by `vars.get("result")` or `${result}`. I disabled it because I didn't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) should do the trick for you:

```
${__groovy('abc'.digest('SHA-256').decodeHex().encodeBase64(),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I would preferred this, it is simpler one

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri T it worked.
Was not having any idea about Groovy functions much. Thanks for the help. :)